# Flutter/Dart - Passing/setting variable outside a Firestore docref.get().then() { ??? }

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Flutter application that converts a string value separated by pipe chars...happen to be song names (ie: 'Rudolf|Jingle Bells|White Christmas') into a ListView...with songnames being the ListTiles.  Long story as to why I'm doing it this way..please bear with me.  I have a Firestore collection called 'sets' and in sets I have a document with a key of SET01.  Then in SET01 I have one field called 'songs'...a text field holding songs separated by pipes.  I call getSetList() to retrieve the text field from Firestore.  I can seem to get the value of 'songs' inside the set01DocRef.get().then((snapshot)....

But I cannot seem to pass that value out of the .then() and back to the function to pass it back to the calling widget.

Any help very much appreciated.

ER

```
String getSetList () {

String songList = 'Loading.....';
DocumentReference set01DocRef = Firestore.instance.collection('sets').document('SET01');

set01DocRef.get().then((snapshot){
  print('String songList inside .then() before assignment:  ' + songList);     //Wagon Wheel|Her Diamonds|Waterfalls
  print('Snapshot value of songs:  ' + snapshot['songs']);         //Wagon Wheel|Her Diamonds|Waterfalls
  songList = snapshot['songs'];     
  print('String songList inside .then() after assignment:  ' + songList);     //Wagon Wheel|Her Diamonds|Waterfalls
});

print('Bueller? Bueller??');
print('String songList outside of .then():  ' + songList);                  

return songList;
}
```

Output:

```
flutter: Bueller? Bueller??
flutter: String songList outside of .then():  Loading.....
Reloaded 0 of 424 libraries in 442ms.
flutter: String songList inside .then() before assignment:  Loading.....
flutter: Snapshot value of songs:  Wagon Wheel|Her Diamonds|Waterfalls
flutter: String songList inside .then() after assignment:  Wagon Wheel|Her Diamonds|Waterfalls
```

**The function skips right past the .get() and immediate returns ... I know this probably has something to do with forcing the system to wait for that value to come back from FS...but I don't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the expected behavior with a `then()` block: the code inside that block is called asynchronously once the data has been loaded, so call code that requires the data has to be inside of the `then()` block.

Luckily Dart has an `await` keyword to make this easier. It essentially replaces the `then()` block:

```
Future<String> getSetList () async {
  String songList = 'Loading.....';
  DocumentReference set01DocRef = 
  Firestore.instance.collection('sets').document('SET01');

  snapshot = await set01DocRef.get();
  print('String songList inside .then() before assignment:  ' + songList);     
  //Wagon Wheel|Her Diamonds|Waterfalls
  print('Snapshot value of songs:  ' + snapshot['songs']);         //Wagon 
  Wheel|Her Diamonds|Waterfalls
  songList = snapshot['songs'];     
  print('String songList inside .then() after assignment:  ' + songList);     
  //Wagon Wheel|Her Diamonds|Waterfalls

  print('Bueller? Bueller??');
  print('String songList outside of .then():  ' + songList);  
  return songList;
}
```

Note that any calls to `getSetList()` must now also use `await`:

```
var setlist = await getSetList();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response...sorry if I should know how this should work...but I tried the line:

snapshot = await set01DocRef.get();

and got snapshot not defined ... changed it to 

var snapshot = await set01DocRef.get();

and the await shows error "Unexpected text await"

Again thanks for the help.

Comment: I forgot to mark the method as async. Added that now. For more on this, see https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore and https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures

Comment: Thanks again...I think I'm very close.  I figured out needing the 'async' but then it wanted my String getSetList() to be Future<String> getSetList() ... so I ended up with: Future<String> getSetList () async {...} Which gives me the string value.  But when I try to call it using: var setList = await getSetList(); ... I start runnign into the 'await' having errors again...I will read up on docs below ... if there is something obvious about how I need to call it please let me know.  Thanks !!

Comment: I am not sure of best practices on Stack Overflow...but am going to accept this answer as it heads me in the direction of an answer...and make a new post with my updated code and current understanding of the problem.

Comment: Im actually going to give it a try myself. My answer was based on previous experience with Firebase Auth, and I'd like to learn how that works with Firestore (where I've only done streams so far).

Comment: Any method calling using `await` will itself have to marked as `async`.