# Flutter - Sending SQL data to a ListView

Tags: database, sqlite, dart, flutter, filesystems

Using the flutter package [sqflite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) I've managed to save data from a news source to a database, such as `title`, `description` and more.

Please take the time to look at this application created [database file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MUjDq78avRF05l5nJDben5dwPne4Clcw) that follows my structure.

This is how I create the database, and how I save data to it from an online source.

```
var title = articles[index].title;
var description = articles[index].description;
var url = articles[index].url;
var urlToImage = articles[index].urlToImage;
var publishedAt = articles[index].publishedAt;

var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, 'saved_articles.db');

Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  // When creating the db, create the table
  await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE Article (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publishedat TEXT)');
});

print(database);

print(databasesPath);

// Insert some records in a transaction
await database.transaction((txn) async {
  int id1 = await txn.rawInsert(
    'INSERT INTO Article(title, description, url, urltoimage, publishedat) VALUES("$title", "$description", "$url", "$urlToImage", "$publishedAt")'
  );
  debugPrint('inserted1: $id1');

});
```

**I'm looking for a method in which to send this data straight to an ordered `ListView`**. The end goal for this being a favourites page which saves articles to the user's device for offline viewing.

This is how I'm retrieving specific data for converting into the bottom `title` list.

```
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
String path = join(databasesPath, 'saved_articles.db');

Database database = await openDatabase(path, version: 1,
    onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
  // When creating the db, create the table
  await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE Article (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, url TEXT, urltoimage TEXT, publishedat TEXT)');
});

List<Map> title = await database.rawQuery('SELECT title FROM Article');
List<Map> description = await database.rawQuery('SELECT description FROM Article');
List<Map> url = await database.rawQuery('SELECT url FROM Article');
```

This is what I'm using to send specific queries to list, but I'm not sure where to go from here in terms of creating a viable structure for sending this data to the desired `ListView`

```
List<Map> title = await database.rawQuery('SELECT title FROM Article');
```

Thanks

Comment: it is honestly the same problem as this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53820419/flutter-dart-calling-a-function-that-is-a-futurestring-but-needs-to-retu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question or issue, so please follow up if I'm missing something.

**I'm looking for a method in which to send this data straight to an ordered ListView.**

From this, I understand your question as you are just wondering what to do next in flutter?

If so, I would recommend taking a look at: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/jaguar_serializer

Then here's what I would do

1. Create an Article model, following jaguar's readme OR just make a manual function to convert a map to an instance of Article.

   `import 'package:jaguar_serializer/jaguar_serializer.dart';
   part 'article.jser.dart';
   class Article {
     string title;
     string description;
     string url;
     etc...
   }`

   etc..
2. Run the cli tool
3. Create a query to get a List of all articles, such as (ordering in sql is faster)

   `'SELECT title, description, url FROM Article ORDER BY title'`
4. Map that to a list of articles (again take a look at jaguar readme for creatont a JsonRepo.

   `List<Article> articles = jsonRepo.decodeList<Complete>(response.body);`
5. Then you can just pass in your articles to the ListView in flutter.

   `ListView.builder(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
         itemExtent: 20.0,
         itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
           return Text('entry ${articles[index].title}');
         },
       )`

Comment: Thanks Alan, I’ll take a look at this soon. It seems to be what I need, I think the package you demonstrate will do the trick